# find road distance between current location and specified location

Tags: iphone, ios, json, cllocation

I wants calculate the  **road distance** between Current location and the other location. Which (XML/JSON  Google direction or anyother) API i use (if any) or what is the right way to do this.?

before i try the following. but i wants road distance

Thanks.

```
CLLocation *location1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:long1];

CLLocation *location2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat2 longitude:long2];

NSLog(@"Distance in meters: %f", [location1 getDistanceFrom:location2]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use google direction Json api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/)  You have to provide the intital location detail and final location. Inside the leg array of the json you will get the distance dictionary in which you will have the distance between two locations.

Comment: As anil said you can use the [google direction api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/) for retrieving the geo details between two end location coordinates. The API documentation have the detailed description of how to use and all you need, . .You can draw route, plot points , show direction and you can play with it...... but make sure you have read the Usage Limits presented on the same document. Happy coding